# Курсовая работа по ООП на C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ооп

Помогите, пожалуйста, с выбором темы на курсовую с использованием классов.

Comment: На самом деле ООП & C++ -- очень-очень грустная тема для курсовой.

Comment: Меня много раз просили сделать что-то вроде "..спроэктировать модель авиапорта...", "...спроэктировать модель железной дороги..." и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> с выбором темы на курсовую с использованием классов.

Подойдите к своему руководителю и решите вопрос с ним. Все очень вариативно. Возможно хватит написать простое приложение на том же Qt с созданием собственных элементов управления. Например, попробуйте реализовать табличный компонент самостоятельно. А возможно потребуется "код ради кода". Можете попробовать создать классы для реализации каких-либо математических объектов. Например, матриц, векторов, комплексных чисел и т.д. Как минимум продемонстрировать знания основных концепций ООП и их реализации в С++ сможете. Заодно и потренируетесь с такими унылыми вещами как перегрузка функций и операторов :-) Честно, не знаю, что еще предложить. Проблема в том, что многое уже реализовано. И поэтому писать заново... ну, можно, но только в целях (само-)обучения. А если писать что-то серьезное, то это уже не курсовик, а диплом.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если курсовая на C++ и ООП, то надо статический полиморфизм брать. Это очень даже в тему. Вся эта химия в известной [книге Александреску](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1224782/). Хотя бы красивый такой баянчик будет.